# Sending HttpPost to Server; No Response needed

Tags: java, android, http-post

I want to do an `HttpPost` on Android to update a single row in a database.  I do not need any response, verification, etc.  So I am trying to simplify my code because I think what I have may be redundant.

This is what I have:

```
          try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Do I need all of this?  It seems I can just have

```
          try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
                httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Is this correct?

Comment: there is no reason to not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't eat when I'm not hungry :)

Yes. The second part is good enough. No need to get the response object there if you don't really need it. That is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I got into a bad habbit of cut and pasting a lot of my http calls and then started to look at what I was actually doing and it seemed redundant.  Will mark correct.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Sure. Happens. No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check AQuery library which simplifies Http connections:

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/